# semantic-ui - Modal got no style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I got the snippet of the basic modal on http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/definition and used it on my site.

But the problem is, It got no style. The "yes" or "no" buttons arrent clickable, the alignment is not good, and the close button appears.

The modal:

```
<div class="ui basic modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Archive Old Messages
  </div>
  <div class="image content">
    <div class="image">
      <i class="archive icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>Your inbox is getting full, would you like us to enable automatic archiving of old messages?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="two fluid ui inverted buttons">
      <div class="ui red basic inverted button">
        <i class="remove icon"></i>
        No
      </div>
      <div class="ui green basic inverted button">
        <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
        Yes
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$('.ui.basic.modal').modal('show');
```

The links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/dist/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/waves.css">
    <script src="http://semantic-ui.com/javascript/library/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/waves.js"></script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Knew it!**

**The snippet was the problem. Here are the right snippets:
http://legacy.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html**

**Funny they don't update their main site :|**

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can assume is that you have not included your CSS file correctly. If you go in to the developer tools (CTRL + Shift + I), and look in your console (Top left tab of the panel), does it give any errors?

Comment: Checked, the links are fine, theres also no errors. I think its about the snippet I took from the site :\ I rembember there was an issue with their snippets (something about versions gap..)